# Como trazer dados de outra tabela relacionado com um id_usuario (JOIN???)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:
Usuários

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E investimentos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela do investimento tem o id do usuário. Já estou conseguindo cadastrar. Como faço pra mostrar na tela de um usuário, os investimentos realizados por ele? Já estou conseguindo cadastrar e está com o id do usuário gravado certinho.
A minha tela vai ser essa abaixo, só irei mostrar a data e o valor da tabela de investimentos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que a seguinte `query sql` resolva seu problema:

```
SELECT i.created_date, i.valor 
FROM Usuario AS u JOIN Investimento AS i ON u.id = i.id_usuario 
ORDER BY i.created_date;
```

Como pode ver nesta query adicionei o `ORDER BY` apenas para organizar melhor o retorno da query.

Caso você deseje especificar o id usuário que será retornado a query seria a seguinte:

```
SELECT i.created_date, i.valor 
FROM Usuario AS u JOIN Investimento AS i ON u.id = i.id_usuario 
WHERE u.id = ?????
ORDER BY i.created_date;
```

Onde "?????" é o seu atributo.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas! Funcionou XD